# "Sim Empty" and cannot make calls after upgrade

Tags: dual-sim, 7.1-nougat, cyanogen-os

I have a WileyFox Swift which I recently updated to Nougat. Wileyfox runs Cyanogen natively. I have not rooted it or hacked it in any way. I installed the update by clicking on a reminder that kept popping up telling me to update. So everything has been done in the official manufacturer-defined way.

It has two sims. When I reboot it asks for the sim lock PIN for one of the sims (the other does not have one) so I know it is detecting the hardware. Also I am able to receive SMS on one of the sims. But I cannot make calls, receive calls, or send SMS. When I go to "Settings -> SIM cards" it says both sims are empty.When I try to make a call, instead of giving me the choice of sim, it only offers emergency call.

I have tried rebooting, re-seating the sims, going into recovery mode and clearing the cache partition.

Comment: Check if you still have IMEI by calling *#06#

Comment: Yes I can see both IMEIs

Comment: Have you been able to fix the issue meanwhile? If so, please consider to [answer your own question](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am in exactly the same situation, Wileyfox upgrade to Nougat, and have not found a good fix.

However what has worked (to a point) is as below:

1. Turn off remove sims and battery for at least 5mins
2. Insert 1st SIM, battery and reboot.
3. At this point 1st Sim should be recognised.
4. Turn off remove battery for 1-2mins.
5. Insert 2nd SIM, battery and reboot.
6. Both Sims should now be recognised.
7. Set and check preferences for Calls, Data, SMS etc.
8. Leave phone on!!!! <- A new problem

As soon at the phone is turned off and on again its back to square one :-(.

I guess it could be a specific problem with Cyanogen >>> Nougat, and the firmware handling 2 sims on boot up.

For reference my Sims are o2 and EE.